# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{(n + t^2 x^2)^{3/2}}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis

For what values of $x$ does
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{(n + t^2 x^2)^{3/2}}$$
converge? Is the convergence absolute, conditional, or uniform?

I'm not sure how to begin solving this problem. Evaluating the integral doesn't
seem tractable. Interchanging summation and integration doesn't seem like it gives
anything. So I'm stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(n+t^{2}x^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}\ge n^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

$$\implies\frac{1}{(n+t^{2}x^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}\le\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

$$\implies\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(n+t^{2}x^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}dt\le\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

$$\implies\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(n+t^{2}x^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}dt\le\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd t \over \pars{n + t^{2}x^{2}}^{3/2}}
=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n\root{n + x^{2}}}\
\color{#c00000}{\Large<}\
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n\root{n + 0^{2}}} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{3/2}}
\end{align}